# go to Declaration like Android in Xamarin Studio(xaml)

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, keyboard-shortcuts

In android Studio If we define something on `Xml` file. and define in resource from Another file. and when we right on click on that and select `go to declaration` then that resource file open in Android Studio.

Example :

let's say **abc.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/red">
```

in **colors.xml** file that color is define.

```
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

So In **abc.xml** file if i click on `go to declaration` it will direct me to `colors.xml`.

So How to do this in Xamarin Studio. I am struggling on that issue.

can any have idea or Knowledge about the short cut Key.

Any Help be Appreciated.